# Converting epoch time format saved in a text file to human friendly format

Tags: timestamps

I have a file name simcloud-target.txt where dates are saved in epoch time format i want to  convert all the dates to human friendly format and print it as a list (same as the out put shown below so instead of epoch i want it in human friendly hh:mm:00)

```
sec504@slingshot:~$ cat simcloud-targets.txt
1679450009
1679450014
1679450018
1679450018
1679450022
1679450023
1679450024
1679450024
1679450033
1679450043
1679450046
1679450060
1679450065
1679450071
sec504@slingshot:~$
```

Answer (score 9):

If the Unix timestamps in the file could be prefixed by `@`, then GNU `date` could read them in with `-f`.  We may prefix each timestamp with `@` using `sed` like so:

```bash
sed 's/^/@/' file
```

... and we may then use the output of that with GNU `date` like so:

```bash
date -f <(sed 's/^/@/' file)
```

Given the datestamps in question and my local timezone, this would give us

```
Wed Mar 22 02:53:29 CET 2023
Wed Mar 22 02:53:34 CET 2023
Wed Mar 22 02:53:38 CET 2023
Wed Mar 22 02:53:38 CET 2023
Wed Mar 22 02:53:42 CET 2023
Wed Mar 22 02:53:43 CET 2023
Wed Mar 22 02:53:44 CET 2023
Wed Mar 22 02:53:44 CET 2023
Wed Mar 22 02:53:53 CET 2023
Wed Mar 22 02:54:03 CET 2023
Wed Mar 22 02:54:06 CET 2023
Wed Mar 22 02:54:20 CET 2023
Wed Mar 22 02:54:25 CET 2023
Wed Mar 22 02:54:31 CET 2023
```

You may then set the output format you want as you would usually do with `date`. Here I also show how to use an ordinary pipe instead of a process substitution:

```bash
$ sed 's/^/@/' file | date -f - +'%F %T'
2023-03-22 02:53:29
2023-03-22 02:53:34
2023-03-22 02:53:38
2023-03-22 02:53:38
2023-03-22 02:53:42
2023-03-22 02:53:43
2023-03-22 02:53:44
2023-03-22 02:53:44
2023-03-22 02:53:53
2023-03-22 02:54:03
2023-03-22 02:54:06
2023-03-22 02:54:20
2023-03-22 02:54:25
2023-03-22 02:54:31
```

See the manual for the library function `strftime` (`man 3 strftime`) to see what format placeholders you may use.

Answer (score 5):

Since you can use almost anything, you could use (g)awk:

```
awk '1{$1 = strftime("%F %H:%M:%S", $1); print}' < simcloud-targets.txt
```

yields (because I'm in a different time zone):

```
2023-03-22 02:53:29
2023-03-22 02:53:34
2023-03-22 02:53:38
2023-03-22 02:53:38
2023-03-22 02:53:42
…
```

I offer this, because it will still work even if you have other entries after the timestamp, such as in squid logfiles:

```
1679468468.282    223 redacted_ip TCP_TUNNEL/200 7160 CONNECT redacted_name:443 - HIER_DIRECT/redacted_ip -
```

becomes

```
2023-03-22 08:01:08 223 redacted_ip TCP_TUNNEL/200 7160 CONNECT redacted_name:443 - HIER_DIRECT/redacted_ip -
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this, with `xargs` and `GNU` `date`:

```
$ xargs < file -I{} date -d '@{}' "+%F %T"
```

Or like this, with `bourne`* `bash`, `dash`, `ash`, `yash`, `ksh`, `zsh`, `sh` (but not compliant with `csh` & `fish`):

```
$ while read epoch; do date -d "@$epoch" "+%F %T"; done < file
```

##### Output

```
2023-03-22 08:53:29
2023-03-22 08:53:34
2023-03-22 08:53:38
2023-03-22 08:53:38
2023-03-22 08:53:42
2023-03-22 08:53:43
2023-03-22 08:53:44
2023-03-22 08:53:44
2023-03-22 08:53:53
2023-03-22 08:54:03
2023-03-22 08:54:06
2023-03-22 08:54:20
2023-03-22 08:54:25
2023-03-22 08:54:31
```

---

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
$ perl -nE 'say scalar localtime($_)' file 
Wed Mar 22 08:53:29 2023
Wed Mar 22 08:53:34 2023
Wed Mar 22 08:53:38 2023
Wed Mar 22 08:53:38 2023
Wed Mar 22 08:53:42 2023
Wed Mar 22 08:53:43 2023
Wed Mar 22 08:53:44 2023
Wed Mar 22 08:53:44 2023
Wed Mar 22 08:53:53 2023
Wed Mar 22 08:54:03 2023
Wed Mar 22 08:54:06 2023
Wed Mar 22 08:54:20 2023
Wed Mar 22 08:54:25 2023
Wed Mar 22 08:54:31 2023
```